# vue.js: Radio button not getting reset

Tags: javascript, vue.js

https://jsfiddle.net/q12gmj3w/1/

I have a checkbox that enables/disables two radioboxes (this bit works fine)

On disabling the radioboxes they should also be reset (ie. neither is chosen)

Case 1:

This works for the case where the default selected radiobox is not changed.

ie. click the checkbox, observe the radioboxes are enabled and that one of them is selected.
Now click the checkbox again - and observe that the radioboxes are disabled, and neither is selected.

Case 2:

If however the radiobox selection is changed, then on clicking the checkbox again, the radioboxes are correctly disabled - But the one radiobox stays checked.

Why in case 2 is the radiobox not deselected???

The `console.log` from `updated` indicates that the `radiobuttons` component have received the correct values - yet one radiobox remains checked??

---

I'm trying to understand why the above does not work.

I'm not looking for a solution - as I already have that here https://jsfiddle.net/ks3bf6ro/
Unless of course there's an even better (simpler) way of doing it.